# Define Layout, GUI by Code at Runtime

Tags: iphone, ios, layout

Net Developer planning a new Product.
It will amongs other things generate dynamically its User Interface from a downloaded File.

I read that file and depending on it i create the necesseray buttons, labels, tables etc..

I wish to outsource that similar kind of product for a development for the IPhone..

So my question to Iphone experts is. Is this possible with the Iphone too?
With 'possible' I mean basically if it is technically possible and if it is 'allowed' on MacStore..

Any feedback is much appreciated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user interface files on the iOS, the (the XIB files), are nothing more than a files containing archived objects. So when you create a static interface in Interface Builder, what Xcode actually does is to create objects for all the UI elements, setting the object properties according to your wishes, setting up the object graph (which objects has references to which other object) and finally archives the whole graph into a file. When you load a XIB file, the objects are simply unarchived and you get an object graph with all the UI objects in their desired states.

That means whatever can be done by loading an interface from a XIB file can also be done problematically. All you have to do is creating the objects yourself, setting all the properties as desired and chaining them to the desired object graph. And yes, creating UI problematically is absolutely allowed by the App Stores (for Mac and for iOS), since it does the same thing by hand as loading a XIB file does automated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible and allowed. There are very little UI related operations that can't be done programatically on Cocoa Touch.